# Автоматическое смещение значений(строк) в таблице ексель с условием

Tags: excel, visual-basic, excel-формулы

Имеется [![таблица][1]][1]
Подскажите кто чем сможет,голова уже кругом, как сделать так, чтобы данные в таблице смещались автоматический на одну строку вверх при условии заполнения последней строки.
Например
1,.............
2....Становится в строку 1
3...Становится в строку 2
....и т д
42...При заполнении поднимается в строку 41.
Но строк всегда должно быть 42, и она должна быть пустая.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkBi.jpg

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO! Если я правильно прочитал это *2 становится в 1, 3 становится в 2*, то нужно просто удалять четвёртую строку при каждом внесении данных внизу таблицы? Точнее, из всей таблицы удалить пустые строки, если они вдруг появились, и если заполненных строк осталось больше чем сорок две, удалить сверху лишние? Тогда почему в заголовке *с условием*?

Comment: Т.е. количество строк в таблице статично?  Заполнили снизу, удалили верхнюю строку. Это можно делать не только вручную, но и макросом.

Comment: Немного не правильно. У самого уже каша. У нас 42 статических столбца таблицы от B4:B43 до S4:S43. Строка B43:S43 всегда пустая. Нужно сделать так, чтобы все столбцы от 4 до 43 всегда смещались на один вверх при условии, когда заполняется строка 43. Тоесть при ее заполнении она переходит на 42 и все остальные смещаются вверх. А 43 остается опять пустая

Comment: Наконец то я нормально сформулировал. У нас есть 42 строки, 41 из них постоянно с числами. Чтобы происходило замещение строк на 1 вверх при заполнении последней и последняя всегда оставалась пустая

Comment: Чем не подошел вариант с удалением верхней строки?